# How it possible to filter out calendar items in deleted emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

I'm looking to archive all deleted emails, which unfortunately not working due to:
[Why does Outlook 2010 give the message "Creating a new item from the selected items could take some time...are you sure you create a new item...?](https://superuser.com/questions/258734/why-does-outlook-2010-give-the-message-creating-a-new-item-from-the-selected-ite)

The advice there is to remove the calendar items, but as I have email communications for last couple of years, it pretty difficult to go one by one.

What is the quickest way of filtering and deleting all the old calendar items from "Deleted" folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to deleted items
In the pane which lists all the items in the folder you have a search box
Just below it you have an option to arrange messages ,

- click on it to get a list of options
- select *Arrange by Type*
- all calendar items will be grouped together

  And all deleted calendar items will be on top(atleast in my case it is )

Comment: Thanks, I looked specifically for this, but actually tried to add a "type" column then sort according to it :).

Answer (score 0):

Try using an advanced filter as such:

```
[Message Class] [Contains] [IPM.Schedule.Meeting]
```