# Can I bulk move multiple outlook meetings/appointments from one folder to another?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010

As discussed in [a related question](https://superuser.com/questions/258734/why-does-outlook-2010-give-the-message-creating-a-new-item-from-the-selected-ite), Outlook 2010 does not easily move multiple messages and appointments.  I am using Outlook 2007 and getting this behavior and I think I recall it from Outlook 2003, which I was using until early last year (our company is slow to adopt new software).

Unlike in the referenced question, I want to move messages, appointments, and anything else in the folder.  In this case, I am trying to move items from my exchange "Deleted Items" to a pst "Deleted Items".

I am immediately interested in Outlook 2007 as I expect to be using it for the next few months.  Soon we're switching to 2010 (possibly even before 2012!) so I'm interested in it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to use the archive command. Under the file menu, there is a manual Archive Item (not AutoArchive). You select your Deleted items in your Exchange account, and select the target PST file.  Set the date to today and it will move all the items into a "Deleted Items" folder in the target PST.

Comment: This does exactly what you describe (in particular, I would emphasize the target is the "Deleted Items" folder).  I'm still curious if I can do a targeted move to a pst/folder of my choice, but this will function for me if not.

Comment: You can still multi select items. Just make sure to switch to a list view.  But most people tend to move items based on their age, so I've always heavily advertised the Archive command.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [tool](http://pandali.com/pfm.html) online, hope it helps.